# 2 save methods (sync) in Backbone.js - one to persist and a final complete method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience in saving the model, `.sync`, with a persistent **auto-save** (localStorage) **AND** a **full save/confirm** (RESTful JSON request).

I've been using the backbone-localstorage adapter that overrides the default behaviour but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way than just adding a switch in a custom sync function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function autoSave(model) {
    model.sync = localStorageSync;
    model.save();
    delete model.sync;
}
```

No need to change `Backbone.sync`